# Slow SQL statement on db2 table with 11 000 000 posts

Tags: sql, db2, database-performance

My problem is when I run this statement:

```
select * from ADMIN.TABLE WHERE NOM="" AND PRENOM =""
```

It takes more than 5 minutes because `NOM` and `PRENOM` are not primary keys. How can I improve the performance?

Comment: Thought about setting indexes?

Answer (score 1):

You can speed up this query using an index:

```
select *
from admin.table
where nom = '' and prenom = '';
```

The appropriate index is `admin.table(nom, prenom)`:

```
create index idx_table_nom_prenom on admin.table(nom, prenom);
```

Comment: thank you  but i cant index all my column of table because i have more thane 53 column and more than 11 000 000 line

Comment: What Gordon is proposing an index on the two columns, it does not matter if the table has 2 or 53 or whichever quantity of columns. The index will improve the access to the 11 millions rows, and this will not be a primary column, just a non-unique index.